# Closing frontmost window in Cocoa in an app without a menu bar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, keyboard-shortcuts, statusbar, menubar

I am building a StatusBar App in Cocoa, therefore I have no menu. Having no menu implies not having a "File > Close" menu item, which normally listens to the shortcut "Command + W".

From my StatusBar App the user may open a window to change the preferences and that's where I'm running into problems: The user can *only* close the window by pressing the red dot with the mouse. However, like alle applications I want to support the "Command + W" shortcut as well.

At the moment I see two possibilities to solve this issue:

1. Place an invisible button on the window which listens to the shortcut.
2. Add an application-wide listener for the shortcut and contact the window manually.

Both solutions feel like a misuse of the system. The first solution can lead to unexpected behaviour (the window closes if the user hits the invisible button by chance) and the second solution will still result in a beep, since the window does not know that it handles such a shortcut.

Is there an elegant way to solve this problem? Since the view should know what to do, a solution with just Interface Builder would be perfect. If there is no elegant way, is there a way to enhance the solutions mentioned?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put a File > Close menu item in your MainMenu nib, the shortcut will work, even though the menu isn't visible.

If you choose to implement an app-wide listener for the shortcut instead, you can get rid of the beep by returning nil from the block, so that the original event doesn't get passed on.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And good to know that the menu bar is invisible but "available". I also learned that you cannot recreate the menu bar, therefore I hat to copy it from another app. (I deleted it since it was useless clutter from my point of view.) -- By the way: Getting rid of the beep did not work, since the block has the signature (NSEvent* (^)(NSEvent*)) which disallows me to return nil or NULL. If you find the right solution, I would be interested. Always good to learn something new. :) Thanks again!

Comment: @Florian: It's allowed to return `nil` from that event handler; this stops the event from being dispatched further. It says so in the [description of the `block` argument](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000016-SW17).

Comment: @Josh: You are right, the documentation of the NSEvent method say one could return nil. However the following code doesn't compile on my machine: `[NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask handler:^(NSEvent *theEvent) { return nil; }];`. The compile-error is `error: incompatible block pointer types initializing 'void * (^)(struct NSEvent *)', expected 'struct NSEvent * (^)(struct NSEvent *)'`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Florian: You're declaring the block to have a `void` return type; it needs to have an `NSEvent *` return. `handler:^NSEvent * (NSEvent *theEvent) { return nil; }];`